# inverting PowerExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Since I couldn't respond to the question "Can you give a situation in which you would want to do this?", I will post this situation as a new question. I am plotting a complicated expression with a factor which is `z*Sqrt[1+rho^2/z^2]`. This bombs at `z=0` but I want `Sqrt[rho^2+z^2]` which doesn't (and is correct). The z* form was generated by a coordinate transformation which has a `Sin[ArcTan[rho/z]]`. I know, `Sin` goes -, but the obvious transformation is `rho->r*Sin[theta]` and `theta->ArcTan[rho/z]`.

Comment: How about `Limit[z Sqrt[1 + rho^2/z^2], z -> 0]`.

Comment: The right transformation (which sidesteps your zero division problem) is `Sin[ArcTan[z, rho]]`.

Comment: Unfortunately my plot needs z=0 where this is undefined but Sqrt[rho^2+z^2] is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot your function by taking the limit. So for instance,

```
rho = 1; Plot[Limit[z Sqrt[1 + rho^2/z^2], z -> zval], {zval, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

You can see clearly the discontinuity at z=0. Of course you may also want to plot more. Here rho takes on different values:

```
Clear[rho]; Plot3D[Limit[z Sqrt[1 + rho^2/z^2], z -> zval], {zval, -1, 1}, {rho, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however the problem is that rho should never be negative (radial cylindrical coordinate); the domain of theta being 0<=theta<=pi

Comment: Brian -- I don't understand. In the above, rho goes from 0 to 1 (and hence is never negative).

Comment: My problem is plotting rho for a value of z=0. While your limiting will do the trick,  z Sqrt[1 + rho^2/z^2] is the wrong function. Sqrt[z^2+ rho^2] is correct.  I would have to execute a notebook and then hunt down any z Sqrt[1 + rho^2/z^2] occurrences and wrap it in the Limit (or limit everything) - even it it were correct - which is why I wish I had an InversePowerExpand to use when I know it is legitimate  I just want to programmatically bring the z inside the sqrt - something one does manually with pen and paper all the time and I can't believe there is no simple command.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify)?

```
Simplify[z Sqrt[1+rho^2/z^2], z>=0]
```

> Sqrt[rho^2 + z^2]